# Result Is Accessible Inside Function With `fetch`, But Pending When Returned

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

We're trying to get the response JSON from a GET request.

When we print `result` from inside the `get` function, the JSON gets printed out like you expect.

However, when we return it and ***then*** try to print it, we get a `Promise` stuck on `<pending>`.

Below is our code:

```
"use strict";

async function get(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url);

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`An error occured: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    let result = await response.json();

    console.log("result inside function", result);
    return result;
}

let url = "OUR_URL";
let result = get(url);
console.log("result outside function: ", result);
```

Below is the output:

```
result outside function:  Promise {<pending>}
result inside function {success: true, statusCode: 200}
```

Based on the order of the output statements above, the outer code is executing first before the code inside the function gets resolved despite having `await` inside the function.
Unfortunately, the outside code isn't in an `async` function, so it can't use `await`.

However, when we use `then()` outside the function, we are able to get the response just fine:

```
get(url).then(result => {
    console.log("result outside function, inside then: ", result);
});
```

Below is the output:

```
result inside function {success: true, statusCode: 200}
result outside function, inside then:  {success: true, statusCode: 200}
```

Above, the order of the output statements is as expected, with the inside one executing first before the ouside one.

We ***have*** seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323), but it hasn't clicked for us on JavaScript.

We have three questions:

1. What is JavaScript doing here, exactly?
2. Is there a way to get the response outside the function without having to use `then()`?

   2.1. If the answer to the above is no, is there a way to get the response from inside `.then()` and expose it outside?

Comment: you have to `await` your call to `get`

Comment: You need to understand blocking / non blocking code along with execution stack.. using async on a function above in  the code does not automatically make the code below wait for it to finish.. the async code is simply referenced and pushed aside while it does its work and js continues and moves on to the next line of code..

Comment: @Evert Ah, yes. We noted in the OP that we have seen that answer, but it hasn't quite clicked for us in JavaScript when we posted the question. Thanks for bringing it up  though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `await` the `get` function. Also, side note, use `const` if you're not reassigning the variable.

```js
async function get(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`An error occured: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const result = await response.json();

    console.log("result inside function", result);
    return result;
}

(async () => {
  const url = "OUR_URL";
  const result = await get(URL);
  console.log("result outside function: ", result);
})();
```

Comment: I see, but wrapping the outside call with `async` seems to be the same as using `then()` in that the result will only be accessible within said wrapping. Is there no way to expose the result to outside, non-async/then code?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment, but [top-level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) is a stage 3 candidate for inclusion in the JavaScript specification.

Comment: Ah, I hope that gets implemented someday then!